# Open a Chrome app within a tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

This issue started with version 23 of Google Chrome. My Chrome app opens a tab to display its UI when the launched event fires.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() 
{
   chrome.tabs.create(
   {
      url: "../../index.html"
   });
});
```

This scheme was working previous to version 23 of Google Chrome. Now receiving the following exception when running my app.

```
Error in event handler for 'app.runtime.onLaunched': Cannot call method 'create' of undefined TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined
```

After checking the `chrome` object in developer tools I notice that `chrome.tabs` is undefined.

I know that I dont have to explicitly set a "tabs" permission in my manifest.json because according to http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html the create, update, and remove methods dont require the "tabs" permission.

After trying to explicitly add the "tabs" permission to the manifest.json file I then receive this message on chrome://chrome/extensions/ for the app.

```
There were warnings when trying to install this extension: 'tabs' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, and this is a packaged app.
```

If I am going by the chart given by https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/choosing and have chosen a packaged app because my app's UI is not small and I dont intend on extending Chrome's UI and I cannot make use of `chrome.tabs` then how can I open my app's UI inside of a new or existing tab without having to create a popup window (which is very annoying and not user friendly)?

Comment: I dont see there is API `chrome.app.runtime` for chrome extensions, it's only available for chrome app. http://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index.html

Comment: right, it is a packaged app..

Comment: So there are no `chrome.tabs` API for packaged app I think. http://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried window.open() in chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me:
just remember to put in the file name you want to open within the brackets!!!

Comment: This is not supported and should be avoided. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=252464